# Wordpress main website and mobile website duplicate content.

Tags: wordpress, seo, duplicate-data, mobile-website

Basically a client has asked for his `WordPress` website to be turned into a mobile website as well. I have never attempted this and know nothing about `SEO`.

However the issue has arisen that this may cause duplicate content issues with `Google`, and therefore both sites may be dropped in the rankings.

I was looking at turning the website into a mobile site via one of the available WordPress mobile website plugins.

My question is if duplicate content will be an issue? Has anyone ever tried this?

After doing some reading I kind of think it may be possible to tell `Google` not to index the mobile website, although as I understand it It would be the same set of files. So I am unsure that if I tell it not to index one of them, that it will drop the other one as well.

Can anyone with WordPress and `SEO` knowledge clear this up for me?

Comment: Why don't you suggest a responsive theme to the client?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you have two **indexed** URLs with same text, there is duplicate content. And for Google, duplicate content is always an issue.

If you decide to no to index the mobile version of site, there will be not duplicate content because only one version of site will be indexed by Google.

Duplicate content is independent of your CMS (Wordpress), it's just a story about two **indexed** pages with same text.